# Responsive content to accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I am having a bit of trouble getting an accordion menu to work. Basically, I would like a 4 column layout which then becomes an accordion menu when the browser is resized to less than 600px. It ALMOST works, for example if you visit the size when your browser is less than 600px already, then it works.

However if you start at desktop size then resize the browser down to below 600px and try and click on the headers, it doesn't work for some reason. Not getting any errors, just not working (content areas don't expand).

I've made a quick demo of what I am trying to do, and it should be fairly simple, I just can't get it to work (lack of sleep probably doesn't help)!

[Link to demo](http://wickywills.com/misc/responsive-accordion.html)

Thanks in advance for any help :)

James

Comment: I guess you apply the `click` function to the `h2` elements multiple times while resizing which causes the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    footerAccordion(); // Display footer as accordion on mobile sizes
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    footerAccordion(); // Display footer as accordion on mobile sizes
}); 

function footerAccordion() {

    if (window.innerWidth < 601) { /* NOTE THIS... */

        $('.col .mobslider').hide();
        $('.col').find('h2').click(function () {

            if (window.innerWidth < 601) {
                $(this).parent().find('.mobslider').stop().slideToggle();
            } else if (window.innerWidth > 600) { /* WHAT's THIS THAN FOR ? */
                $('.col .mobslider').show();
            }

        });

    } else if (window.innerWidth > 600) {

        $('.col .mobslider').show();

    }

}
```

Makes sense?
A solution would be:

```
var winIsSmall;
$(window).on('load resize', footerAccordion );

function footerAccordion() {
    winIsSmall = window.innerWidth < 601;
    $('.col .mobslider').toggle(!winIsSmall);
}

$('.col').find('h2').click(function () {
    if(winIsSmall){
        $(this).parent().find('.mobslider').stop().slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's certainly a cleaner way, thanks, though I'm still getting the same issue with this code. If you start at a desktop size then resize the browser to a smaller (mobile) size, the toggle tabs don't work :(

Comment: Because still, everytime you resize, you add an additional `click` function.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan, clicks don't work at all now - hope it's not something silly I'm doing wrong? Appreciate the help

Comment: It's the `document.ready(function() {...})` or in your case the wrapping `$(function(){...})`. You need to apply the `click` event after the DOM finished loading.

Comment: @Roko C. Bulja, thanks - this worked! Appreciate your time :)