# Responsive tabbed content to accordion - accordion closes when tab clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, zurb-foundation, accordion

I have set up three columns to move into an accordion for smaller screens. I am using the method recommended here:
[Responsive content to accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20968728/responsive-content-to-accordion)

My problem is that I have tabbed content within one of the accordions (using Foundation tabs for these) and, when you click on one of the tabs, instead of just showing the content for that tab, it closes the accordion. I thought the script (below) was only allowing the h3 to toggle the accordion, but obviously not. Or, maybe the Foundation script is overriding? Any ideas.

Here is the accordion script:

```
$(function(){

  var winIsSmall;
  $(window).on('load resize', homeAccordion );

  function homeAccordion() {
    winIsSmall = window.innerWidth < 641;
    $('.columns .mobslider').toggle(!winIsSmall);
  }

  $('.columns').find('h3').click(function () {
    if(winIsSmall){
        $(this).parent().find('.mobslider').stop().slideToggle();
    }
  });

});
```

Here is the page with the issue when viewing at the small screen size:
http://www.easternflorida.edu/
Click on 'Calendar' and then select a filter for the calendar content (e.g. Athletics.)

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: winIsSmall is not defined `

Comment: Realized that it is a callback on the tabs I'm using that is causing the issue. Is there anything I can add to this that will keep the accordion open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what was going on here. I used a callback function posted here:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4611

It was resizing the window and causing toggled divs to revert to default state.

I just changed the callback from this:

```
$(document).foundation({
  tab: {
    callback : function (tab) {
      $(window).trigger('resize');
    }
  }
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).foundation({
  tab: {
    callback : function (tab) {
      $(document).foundation('equalizer');
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks to the last commenter on that Foundation post.